# Convert date to first of current month if date is previous to current month

Tags: sql, ms-access, iif

I have a query with an `IIF()` expression in one column that I am using to identify if a date is previous to the current month to then amend it if so. So if I run the query on `19th March 2014` and the `EffFrom` date is before 1st March 2014, I would want that column entry to now appear as `1st March 2014`.

I am using the below expression which is pretty much doing what I want, however I know it is not considering the year -- i.e. it is changing an entry of `1st Jan 2015` to be `1st March 2014`.

```
EffFrom: 
IIf(Month([Table.Efffrom])"Less than symbol"Month(Date()),Date()-Day(Date())+1,[Table.Efffrom])
```

Can someone correct the expression for me?

Comment: I tried to change your title for better clarity.  I hope it is correct and says what you want to do.

Comment: Is this about transforming `Efffrom` dates from previous months to the first of the current month?  And what is the purpose of `"Less than symbol"`? ... is that supposed to mean an actual `<` character?

Comment: Hi Smandoli. Unfortuanelty that's not what I want to achieve. I want all Efffrom dates that are before the current month to be appear as the first of the current month.

Comment: Hi HansUp, yes that is what I want to so. And yes it should be < but when I had that symbol it didn't show the rest of my expression. Thanks

Comment: @RosscoP, I like your new title.  +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I interpreted *"if I run the query on 19th March 2014 and the efffrom date is before 1st March 2014 I would want that column entry to now appear as 1st March 2014"* to mean you want something like this from a query run today (Mar 19th 2014):

```
id Efffrom   adjusted_date
 1  1/1/2014      3/1/2014
 2  3/1/2014      3/1/2014
 3 3/31/2014     3/31/2014
 4  1/1/2015      1/1/2015
```

If that is correct, your `IIf` expression can use `DateSerial` to check whether `Efffrom` is before the first of this month, and transform the older dates.

```sql
SELECT
    y.id,
    y.Efffrom,
    IIf
        (
            y.Efffrom < DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), 1),
            DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), 1),
            y.Efffrom
        ) AS adjusted_date
FROM YourTable AS y;
```

Comment: That'll do it! I'd come across Date Serial but couldn't quite figure it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i do to get the first day of the next month

```
EffFrom: DateAdd("m",1,CDate(Format([Table.Efffrom],"m/\1/yy")))
```